# How to open option list of HTML select tag on onfocus()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, jquery-events

My HTML code looks like below:

```
   <select id = "demo2">
        <option value = "---select---">---select---</option>
        <option value = "1">Oranges</option>
        <option value = "2">Apples</option>
        <option value = "3">Pears</option>
        <option value = "4">Kiwis</option>
        <option value = "5">Bananas</option>
        <option value = "6">Banansasas</option>       
        <option value = "7">Grapes</option>
   </select>
```

How do I open the option list of the `select` tag on `onfocus()` events?

Comment: The mechanics of the option list UI are up to the browser and/or OS, there's no way to control it from Javascript. If you want more control, replace the `<select>` with a CSS menu, perhaps by using a plugin like Select2.

Comment: `@Barmar` will you please provide me any link or example related to `Select2`

Comment: I really agree with @Barmar

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @Barmar FYI This is a not an uncommon request. There should be a way to do this. `myList.open()` is typical in other frameworks. Tagging @W3C

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The answers below show how to do it. Although it seems like a strange request, since clicking on a manu normally opens it in most browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr("size",$(this).attr("expandto"));
        var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";
        $(x).fadeTo(50,0);
    });
    $('select').blur(function(){
        $(this).attr("size",1); 
        var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";       
        $(x).fadeTo('fast',1.0);            
    });
});
```

[Link for demo example](http://www.php-insite.com/autoexpand_select.html)

Comment: *[**Provide context for links**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Answer (score 1):

**Complete code for requirement like this question..for reference purpose..**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto-expand SELECT</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').focus(function () {
        $(this).attr("size", $(this).attr("expandto"));

    });
    $('select').blur(function () {
        $(this).attr("size", 1);

    });
    $('select option').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().attr("size", 1);
        $(this).parent().val(this.value);

    });

    $('select').live('keypress', function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) // the enter key code
        {
            $(this).attr("size", 1);

        }
    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    select{position:absolute}
    .selectHolder{position:relative; height:45px}
    h4{margin:10px 0;}
    h5{margin:50px 0 0 0; text-align:center; font-weight:normal }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin:30px auto;  width:400px; border:1px #888 solid; padding:20px; background-color:#F8F4F0">
<h3 style="text-align:center">Tab In, To Open Select Box</h3><br/><br/>
<form>
<input style="width:230px" type="text" name="start" value="Start here then tab to next input" tabindex="1" /><br/><br/> 
<h4>One to Seven</h4>
<div class="selectHolder">
    <select class="select" size="1" expandto="7" tabindex="2">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
    </select>
</div>
<h4>One to Ten</h4>
<div class="selectHolder" >
    <select class="select" size="1" expandto="10" tabindex="3">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
        <option value="7">Seven</option>
        <option value="8">Eight</option>
        <option value="9">Nine</option>
        <option value="10">Ten</option>    
    </select>
</div>
<h4>One to Four</h4>
<div class="selectHolder tab4">
  <select class="select" size="1" expandto="4" tabindex="4">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
</div>
<h4>One to Dog</h4>
<div class="selectHolder tab4">
  <select class="select" size="1" expandto="5" tabindex="5">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
        <option value="2">BAT</option>
        <option value="3">BIRD</option>
        <option value="4">CAT</option>
        <option value="5">DOG</option>    
  </select>
</div>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Find jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEfft/8/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
   <select id = "demo2">
        <option disabled="true" selected="true" value = "---select---">---select---</option>
        <option value = "1">Oranges</option>
        <option value = "2">Apples</option>
        <option value = "3">Pears</option>
        <option value = "4">Kiwis</option>
        <option value = "5">Bananas</option>
        <option value = "6">Banansasas</option>       
        <option value = "7">Grapes</option>
   </select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#demo2').on('focus',function() {
    var optCount = $(this).children('options').length;
    $(this).attr('size', optCount);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/PWUZp/12/)

Comment: `@DevlshOne` something wrong with your demo..jsFiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

in your code you can place this code **select id = "demo2"** with this code  **select id = "demo2" onfocus="myFunction(this)**   fore highlight your Option.

Comment: and also add the style code in the uper the header  <script>
function myFunction(x)
{
x.style.background="yellow";
}
</script>

Comment: downvoted - where does the OP mention highlighting or changing the background color of the select statement?

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#selectBox').focus(function() {
        $(this).attr('size',4);
        $(this).css('position',"absolute");
        $(this).css('x-index',"1000");
    });
    $('#selectBox').blur(function() {
        $(this).attr('size',1);
  $(this).css('position',"relative");
  $(this).css('x-index',"0");
    });
 $('#selectBox2').focus(function() {
        $(this).attr('size',4);
        $(this).css('position',"absolute");
        $(this).css('x-index',"1000");
    });
    $('#selectBox2').blur(function() {
        $(this).attr('size',1);
        $(this).css('position',"relative");
        $(this).css('x-index',"0");
    });
});
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid #00C;">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="add" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="city" id="city" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="tel" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="home" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="cun" id="cun" />
    <br />
    <select id="selectBox">
      <option value="1" >1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <br />  
    <br />  
    <br />
    <select id="selectBox2">
      <option value="1" >1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>   
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CLECK TO SEE JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/thamindu/rh93otf5/)

Comment: Press tab to traverse through Elements Make sure Jquery library is imported to the html