# Opening a html select option on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I had asked a question about [How to open option list of HTML select tag on onfocus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943475/how-to-open-option-list-of-html-select-tag-on-onfocus). At that time it solved my problem but I missed one problem that every time on opening a html select option `onfocus` next select option went disappear.

I not able to find whats going wrong with this code.
here is link for that problematic question  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/7).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to keep multiple drop down menus open at the same time?

Comment: `@Ioannis Karadimas` no. i want to open select onfocus one by one,but select one next select tag goes disappear.like on selecting `One to Seven` at that time `One to Ten` goes disappear.

Comment: for reference : `http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/8/` this link satisfy my need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what the lines

```
var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";
$(x).fadeTo(50,0);
```

do. They hide the next select, because otherwise it would show on top of the expanded one.

This isn't a good solution at all though. Instead i'd use z-index to prevent that from happening:

```
$('select').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",$(this).attr("expandto")).css('z-index',2);        
});
$('select').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",1).css('z-index','1');         
});
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",1).css('z-index','1');
});
```

It would be even better to use a class instead of inline style. But i used that just as a demonstration.

http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/1/

Comment: `@Andy` i appriciate your answer but while select optionlist open at same time i tring to use up-down arrow key, optionlist goes close.

Comment: `@Andy` above answer solved my problem but i try it on internet explorer onmouse click event option can't get selected. try this link on internet explorer `http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/8/`. please help me out.thank in advance.

Comment: `@Andy` onclick event not working on Internet Explorer find this http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/8/. Please help me out...

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/k4eV4/ I hope that's what you want. I'm also not sure if opening a select on focus is worth all that effort and click handler trickery

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the fadeTo function. check this http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",$(this).attr("expandto"));
    var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";
    //$(x).fadeTo(50,0);
 });
 $('select').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",1); 
    var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";       
    //$(x).fadeTo('fast',1.0);
 });
 $('select').change(function(){
    $(this).attr("size",1); 
    var x = "select[tabindex='" + (parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'),10) + 1) + "']";       
    //$(x).fadeTo('fast',1.0);            
 }); 
});
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `@bhb` thanks for answer but now on up-down arrow key,optionlist goes close.

Comment: Can you please be a more specific? Thanks

Comment: please refer this `http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/7/` here. while focusing on first select, optionlist window open on that if i try to use keyboard updown arrow at same time optionlist that opening on onfocus goes close.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that. I am selecting the options with the keyboard and everything is working as expected.

Comment: `@bhb` onclick event not working on Internet Explorer find this jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/8. Please help me out..

Comment: what are you trying to do??