# Show dropdown when keyboard tab button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, onfocus

I have a dropdownlist and I would like to have it to show the list when user clicked on the keyboard tab button tried a few ways shown online but it is not working. The dropdownlist are html dropdown and select2 dropdown.

For the 3rd method , the dropdown shows when the tab button is clicked but when I select another value on the dropdown and clicked on TAB button , it still remains as the original value. May I know how could I solve it ?

My dropdown:

**DropDown1**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <select class="form-control" id="sauces"></select>
  </div>
    $('#sauces').select2({
      data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: "Banana"
      }, {
        id: 1,
        text: "Red Velvet"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "Vanilla"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "Strawberry"
      }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "Chocolate"
      }],

    });
```

**DropDown2**

```
<select>
  <option value="round">Round</option>
  <option value="square">Square</option>
  <option value="circle">Circle</option>
  <option value="mini" selected>Mini</option>
</select>
```

Methods I had tried:

1)

```
        function select2Focus() {
        var select2 = $(this).data('select2');
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!select2.opened()) {
                select2.open();
            }
        }, 0);  
    }
```

2)

```
$('.input-group input').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 9){ // tab
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').click();
        $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu a:first').focus();
    }
});
```

3)

```
$(document).on('focus', '.select2', function() {
    $(this).siblings('select').select2('open');
});
```

Comment: could you add some of your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer from  *http://jsfiddle.net/PpTeF/1/*
I've remove the change function below for my project as I would like user to be able to tab when they are choosing the values in the dropdown.
`$('select').change(function(){
        $(this).attr("size",1).css('z-index','1');
    });`     where it could show the dropdown when keyboard tab key is clicked, but this is for the html select dropdown. Hope that this could help those that are finding similar solution.

Codes are found in *[Opening a html select option on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226939/opening-a-html-select-option-on-focus)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Hi, I had added it like this , May I know if I am doing correctly? As the dropdown value is still not updated. Thanks for your help.
<script>
  $(document).on('focus', '.select2', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
});
   </script>